# Simple battery backup

Tags: transistors, relay

I am experiencing sudden outage in my area from few seconds to a hour or so. I am currently using this circuit. Turning on and off every time for a blackout is just annoying. I just want to cut off Line A when the battery charger is giving power to the battery. Which transistor should I use?(looking for commonly used parts) I guess relay will delay on switching. So I am asking if it can turn battery backup without interruptions And how do I put it in this circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjsIFv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(PS. I don't want to use my ups on my router. It takes lot of time to charge and it drains quick. I am looking for a circuit that can simply just cut the line A when the charger power is present. Thank you.)

Comment: In what way is a relay not an improvement over what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 1):

So, from your explanation, you want to switch off the equipment whenever there is grid power. Or is there a separate connection to the output of the sw2?

You can get all the functionality to do this with a small ups. won't mention a price as that varies by location etc. I have one for my router and wifi - works a treat : made by Trust.

Comment: UPS doesn't last that long. This unused battery can backup for 4 hrs my ups cant do that 8 min tops. And I lose the efficiency. So for your question I want to cut off battery power along with battery charger when the grid is working.

Comment: UPS are available that last longer than 4 hours... Update your question and diagram so it is clear.

Comment: I know I wanted to use my battery on this. Thought you could help :)

Comment: I did try to help when I asked for the clarified detail which so far you have not done.

Comment: Oh, on schematics you can see on the right there is my router's PSU which is always  connected to grid. When psu loses its power I can turn on the switch for the battery backup. I don't want to connect the battery with router when the charger is still getting power from grid. I just asked if there is a solution to use a transistor to detect if there is any power coming from the charger. If it does then cut off the LINE A.